# Get value of List Item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

How to get value and index of list item `onClick` event with jQuery?
 For example:

```
<ul id='uItem'>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 14):

Combine the use of [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) (or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), if you wish):

```
$('#uItem li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#uItem li').click(function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 alert('Text ' + $this.text() + 'Index ' + $this.index());
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/yccyJ/1/

Answer (score 6):

If you had set a value attribute for your li:

```
    <ul id='uItem'>
    <li value="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li value="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li value="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li value="item4">Item 4</li>
    </ul>
```

, then you can retrieve it using jQuery like this:

```
$('#uItem li').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var selKeyVal = $this.attr("value");
    alert('Text ' + $this.text() + 'value ' + selKeyVal);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').click(function(){ 
     var value = $(this).text();
     var index = $('li').index($(this));
});
```

check [this](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for more details

Comment: You can't use `val()` on list items.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the index function, http://api.jquery.com/index/