# Get Values of sub elements of clicked class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class `amt` and when that class is clicked I want to get the values of the clicked `<h6>`, `<span>` and `<label>` tags. 
How do I do this in jquery? I have already seen a question here [Get value of List Item with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548827/get-value-of-list-item-with-jquery) but it uses same

under  tag but i have to get different elemet value under same tag

```
<li class="amt" id="diecut_am1">
    <h6>50</h6>
    <span>$59.00</span>
    <label>$51.30</label>
</li>
<li class="amt" id="diecut_am2">
    <h6>100</h6>
    <span>$68.00</span>
    <label>$61.20</label>
</li>
```

Comment: what value you want exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value of List Item with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548827/get-value-of-list-item-with-jquery)

Comment: the code i want to getvallues of the clicked ones <h6> , <span> etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".amt").click(function() {
    var elem1 = $(this).find("h6").html();
    var elem2 = $(this).find("span").html();
    var elem3 = $(this).find("label").html();

    alert(elem1);
    alert(elem2);
    alert(elem3);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kLe5kLc3/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.amt').on("click", function() {
       var h6 = $(this).find('h6').text();
       var span = $(this).find('span').text();
       var label = $(this).find('label').text();
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/12q12k52/

Answer (score 1):

here's the JS way :

```js
var amt = document.querySelectorAll('.amt')

//add event listener to all .amt elements
var amtArr = [].slice.call(amt)

amtArr.forEach(function (x) {
    x.addEventListener('click', listChilds, true)
});


//we retrive the target properties
function listChilds(e) {

    console.log(e.path[1]) //all the children 

    //if you want one in particular it would be
    console.log(e.target.childNodes[0])

}
```

```html
<li class="amt" id="diecut_am1">
     <h6>50</h6>
 <span>$59.00</span>

    <label>$51.30</label>
</li>
<li class="amt" id="diecut_am2">
     <h6>100</h6>
 <span>$68.00</span>

    <label>$61.20</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) of the clicked elements

```
$(this).children()
```

Comment: Here you will never get Reference of $(this)